# Supress empty initialization of object in Python

Tags: python, class, constructor

I want to force the use of a specific number of arguments when creating an instance of some class. From what I have read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), even if I declare

```
class someClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2..):
        # whatever
```

it would still be possile to instantiate someClass like this:

```
a = someClass()
```

I am very new to python, so my only idea of enforcing that would be to overload an empty constructor and throwing an exception in it. But I would prefer something that enforces it at compile time already. Is that possible?

Comment: Where exactly does it says you can initialize such class like this? Try to run the code first.(Note that `self` is a special positional argument that is added by Python when you call a method.)

Comment: it would not run, you would get a `TypeError` without passing required positional arguments

Comment: So as soon as i define an __ init __, it automatically enforces what I want?

edit: I tried to run it, but I got a typeerror because I used inheritance and had another error there. I have it working now, and it behaves as you two stated. My bad, asked a bit prematurely.

Comment: You can only instantiate without passing any arguments if you make the parameters optional; `def __init__(self, arg1=None, ...):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will see when you try it, if your `__init__` method has required arguments, then you cannot create the object without passing those arguments.  But I will caution you that "forcing" your caller to do something might be going against the Python grain.  Often, the Python mantra is, "document your API, and then let the caller do what the caller is going to do."